# Anylogic Measuring Time in a Service-block

Tags: time, service, average, anylogic, measure

does anyone know how to measure the time in a service-block, in particular, the average time in the queue of the service block?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly

- Use the 'On enter' action to record the queue entry time (via the `time()` function) in the agent (which will require using a custom agent type with a `double` variable called `serviceEntryTime` or similar)
- Use the 'on seize' action to measure the duration until it left the queue (by seizing the resources it needs) via `time() - serviceEntryTime` and add this value to a Statistics object which will then give you various statistics (including the mean) via functions it provides.

Or split your Service block into a TimeMeasureStart -- Seize -- TimeMeasureEnd -- Delay -- Release sequence. The TimeMeasureEnd block has a built-in histogram data object which will give you the mean via `blockName.distribution.mean()`.

Comment: thanks! I tried to implement ur 2nd suggestion, but now it is saying that it "cannot convert double to historgramdata. Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: What do you mean by my '2nd suggestion'? None of them involve explicitly adding entries to a HistogramData object so the error you state would not occur. You probably need to state exactly what you implemented.